# An Array of x Elements, Max Entry = y, Total of Elements = z

Tags: javascript, combinatorics

In working on something else, I have come across this little brain-burner.

I want to return an array of all the arrays that satisfy this.

1. There are `elArr` elements in the array. Eg if `elArr = 3` then the array looks like `[x,y,z]` where x, y and z are numbers.
2. The maximum entry in any position of the array is `maxNum` and the minimum is 1. So in the example above `[x,y,z]` has the restriction `1 <= x,y,z <= maxNum`.
3. The total of all the elements is `total`. Any array that does not satisfy this is rejected.

This is my place-holder, but quite honestly I think it is rubbish.

Can this be done better?

```
const getAllArr = (ret, a, elLeft, maxNum, totLeft) => {
    if(elLeft === 0 && totLeft === 0){
        ret.push(a);
        return;
    }else if (elLeft === 0 || totLeft < elLeft || (elLeft * maxNum) < totLeft)
        return;
    let i, r;
    for(i=1;i<=maxNum && i <= totLeft;i++){
        getAllArr(ret, a ? [...a, i] : [i], elLeft-1, maxNum, totLeft-i);
    }
};
```

For example

```
let r = [];
getAllArray(r, null, 3, 6, 10);
```

produces

```
[   [6,3,1],
    [5,4,1],
    [4,5,1],
    [3,6,1],
    [6,2,2],
    [5,3,2],
    [4,4,2],
    [3,5,2],
    [2,6,2],
    [6,1,3],
    [5,2,3],
    [4,3,3],
    [3,4,3],
    [2,5,3],
    [1,6,3],
    [5,1,4],
    [4,2,4],
    [3,3,4],
    [2,4,4],
    [1,5,4],
    [4,1,5],
    [3,2,5],
    [2,3,5],
    [1,4,5],
    [3,1,6],
    [2,2,6],
    [1,3,6]
]
```

Comment: This code is nice enough. The middle clause bails out of impossible problems. Its first two disjuncts are range checking on `elLeft` and it doesn't really matter if we check here or within the `for` loop prior to maybe recursing. But it seems like we should prefer to accomplish the`elLeft * maxNum` check prior to recursing. Also, the `for` loop bound mentions `totLeft`. Wouldn't it be better to compare against an expression that uses `elLeft` and `maxNum`? tl;dr: Avoid making inquiries about problems that you can quickly rule out as impossible.